# Unable to install TomCat on Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

Started using Eclipse a week ago and today while i was creating a new server i got this error

[Tomcat Installation Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0KQu.png)

Error occurred installing server: https://dlcdn.apache.org/tomcat/tomcat-10/v10.0.20/bin/apache-tomcat-10.0.20.zip
https://dlcdn.apache.org/tomcat/tomcat-10/v10.0.20/bin/apache-tomcat-10.0.20.zip

Comment: What does it say in "Details"?

Comment: @greg-449 i updated the post with a screenshot of the details. Thanks.

Comment: Please [don't upload text as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13447). Edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. Also see [ask].

Comment: If you follow those URLs then you'll see that this doesn't exist. Only 10.0.22 exist.

Comment: @JoachimSauer then how should i go about it? thats the link eclipse put in when i install New Server > Tomcat v10.0 Server

Answer (score 3):

This is bug [580174](https://bugs.eclipse.org/580174), which is using a download URL for 10.0.20 that expired once Apache released Tomcat 10.0.**21**. You can manually download and unzip https://dlcdn.apache.org/tomcat/tomcat-10/v10.0.22/bin/apache-tomcat-10.0.22.zip and use the directory it creates as the installation's location.

This will be fixed in the 2022-09 release.